# Accessing a file in a subproject of xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I have a phonegap application where it has added a cocoa touch static library project to it as a sub project. I need to access an xml file that is embedded to the library project.

```
NSString *configXmlFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"configurationFile" ofType:@"xml"];

NSString *xmlContent=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:configXmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

that's how I access a file in the project usually. but since this is a sub project, I can't access the path like this.Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drag the file in question from your subproject in the Project Navigator to the "Copy Resources" build phase in your master Xcode project. Let me know if you'd like me to explain in detail.

Comment: thanks for your response. I did the same but It ended up with linker errors while building as a whole. after adding the sub project to the main project, what the points that we need to fix to build it successfully.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You got linker errors when copying a subproject resource into your target executable?

Comment: I am adding a library project to a phonegap application as a sub project.Once I add it as a sub project and then build the application, I get errors. basically the architecture is mismatching. even I wasn't able to access the functions in the library project that are exposed to the outsiders through the header files by simply importing the header files to the required source file in the phoneGap plugin class.

Comment: I see. I don't know much about PhoneGap, but it would be helpful if you updated your question with some of those errors.